# Divisible Random Variables

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose I can write a positive, real valued random variable 
$$ X = m_1 X_1 + m_2 X_2,$$
where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are i.i.d, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d and moreover, the $X_i$ are distributed like $X$.  Also, assume that all the random variables have finite first and second moments ( $\mathbb{E} m_i =1/2$). Is this question studied at all? Do such random variables have to be 'nice'? In particular are there some weak conditions on $X$ under which $\frac{m_1 X_1}{X}$ is Dirichlet?  To me this seems like a close analog of infinitely divisible random variables with very structured dependence but I haven't been able to find any references on it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The $m_i$s can be dependant on the $X_i$s? 

Comment: Actually, everything on the RHS is independent. Thanks. 

Comment: do you have any examples of such things ?